# Was Fringe the first TV show to use the changing Opening credits?

Tags: fringe

Recently I started re-watching the TV show Fringe, and noticed that they used different colored opening credits that indicate the universe the majority of the episode takes place in. [I am only up to season 3, but I understand they use 4 different color schemes to indicate the universes. Blue: Original, Red: Alternate, Black: Observers, Yellow: Final]

- I recall that Supernatural TV show changed the opening credits designs, but AFAIR it was based on seasons. In that, each change in the opening credits indicated a new season.
- The TV show Frazier also changed logos. But that was just a change of color to indicate seasons, and the random variations in the "city skyline" was just random and had no bearing on the episode.

Was Fringe the first show to have a meaningful variation in the opening credits? (Have there been any since? I cant recall any.)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. I just wanted to say I miss Fringe. Also, be sure to rewatch the retro intro. I get a kick whenever I remember the "advanced" technologies from that intro :P

Comment: Babylon 5 changed opening credits, but this was also for each season.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about scifi.

Comment: Hasn't the Simpsons been doing that for decades?

Comment: Warning: TV Tropes link: [Special Edition Title](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpecialEditionTitle)

Answer (score 1):

[Jericho](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jericho_(2006_TV_series)) had a minimalist intro with a subtle change at each episode:

> Each episode's opening title sequence is accompanied by an audio message in Morse code. The messages vary from generic references to cryptic clues, and are always related to the current episode in some way. The messages were broadcast at 15 words per minute at a frequency of 1000 Hz.

The show was aired in 2006, so two years before Fringe.

Answer (score 1):

Start Trek: Enterprise's episode [In a Mirror, Darkly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly) aired April 22, 2005.  The credits changed to be violent and militaristic because the episode was set in the Mirror Universe.

Comment: I believe Buffy the Vampire Slayer also did this with the 2000 episode "Superstar" where minor character Jonathan used magic to make himself the center of everything.  The credits for that episode altered to include scenes of him doing heroic things.

Answer (score 0):

Inspector Morse (7 series (1987–1993) and 5 specials (1995–2000)):

> In the documentary, The Mystery of Morse, Pheloung states that he occasionally spelled out the name of the killer in Morse code in the music, or alternatively spelled out the name of another character as a red herring.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_Morse_(TV_series)